# Can we login on a website with pure Python urllib, modify some form values, and submit? (without Selenium browser automation)

Tags: python, selenium, paypal, urllib

Is it possible to make a script that automatically:

1. Connects to the PayPal HTTPS website
2. Logs in with username + password
3. Goes to a [specific URL](https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome?reportType=DLOG)
4. Modifies a few values in the dropdown lists
5. Clicks on a button

All of this from Python with standard methods like `urllib.request`?

```
import urllib.request; s = urllib.request.urlopen('https://example.com').read().decode()
```

Or because of the login involved, do we have to do it by "automating" or "faking" a real browser, using `Selenium` methods / or other methods à la `PhantomJS`? (I'd rather not have to do that, if possible)

[image]

---

*Context*: I've looked into various places and asked their support by email + phone, but it seems that PayPal **doesn't offer access to an API to trigger the generation and download of a CSV report of all transactions** between e.g. 01/01/2020 and 31/01/2020 ... *except* if you have > 20k sales per month and in this case you have access to their [Reporting API + reports on a FTP server](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/payflow-reports/use-the-api/).

If this is not the case this Reporting API is not available, and you have to manually log in, go to the page https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome?reportType=DLOG (see screenshot above), click in various lists, click `Create report`, wait a few minutes/hours, re log-in, go back  on this page, and finally click on `Download`. This is a boring task to do each month (and their website is rather slow in general) that I would like to automate.

Comment: Do you know if javascript is handing the drop-down when you mentioned "modify a few values in the dropdown lists".  Anytime javascript is dynamically making changes to the DOM `urllib.request` will not have access to that.

Comment: @Jortega I'll have a look at the HTML if the dropdown lists can be modified with an URL parameter

Comment: @Jortega it seems to be JS indeed, the submit button "Create Report" does not seem to be a classical `<form> <input type="submit">` attached to a simple GET or POST. It's probably JS with Ajax / XMLHttpRequest that handles this (the source code of the page is rather difficult to read, and multiple .js files are called, so I wouldn't be able to find this easily)

Comment: I am afraid you will need some way to interact with the JS and Ajax. Unfortunately the browser is running the JS for you that is why selenium works.

Answer (score 2):

The correct link to SFTP reports is: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/reports/sftp-reports/

And those are all stricly **daily** report files, not monthly or any other time period. You'd have to read and parse in each daily file to cover the time period you desire.

---

It is theoretically possible to emulate the PayPal website UI with something like urllib or [mechanize.Browser](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) and automate requesting an activity log file and downloading it. But that's a fair amount of work for something you're only going to be doing once a month, and may break when PayPal changes their site. The login portion is particularly tricky to automate, since PayPal can require additional verification beyond just a password.

If you are going to automate some portion of this, I would recommend only doing so inside the browser (Tampermonkey, Selenium, etc; note that Tampermonkey blacklists paypal.tld by default, for your own protection against importing a malicious script)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you have access to SFTP reports? According to the support (local to my country), it seems not available for me (I'll retry, who knows? Maybe they would enable it this time?). Was it easy to have it enabled for you? Daily files would be fine for me, I would parse each file with no difficulty with a small Python script.

Comment: What is [mechanize.Brower](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/forms.html) exactly (never heard of it)? Is it an extension of urllib, specifically for forms? How would you emulate the Paypal UI with it (it's ok for me to spend hours on this, I'll learn a new technique, and anyway, Paypal changes their page UI *very rarely*, some of their pages still have their 2004 look ;)).

Comment: Thanks for the info about Tampermonkey (scripting directly in the browser with an extension).

Comment: I have worked with merchants who had SFTP reporting, which is a feature geared towards those with a large volume of transactions. The 20k threshold sounds like a reasonable one before PayPal would consider enabling it, but I'm not informed on the policy.  Yes mechanize gives a framework to automate forms, among possibly other things (I last used the module when it was known as "ClientForm").